# Is the vertx WebClient.send() method blocking or non-blocking

Tags: vert.x

I have a verticle which has a handler that calls Vertx's Webclient in the event loop thread. Is the actual underlying API call synchronous or asynchronous? Does it block my event loop thread? Assume my API call takes 30 seconds to return.

```
public class MyHandler implements Handler<Message<JsonObject>> {
  WebClient myClient;

  public MyHandler(WebClient myClient) { this.myClient = myClient; }

  @Override
  public void handle(Message<JsonObject> message) {
      myClient
        .get("url.com/the/path")
        .send().onSuccess(result -> { message.reply(result.bodyAsJson()); }
  }
}
```

Do I need to wrap the webclient call with Vertx.executeBlocking(p -> {/*api call here*/})? Is the API call blocking? Note that my verticle is a regular one not a worker verticle.

Answer (score 1):

All Vert.x APIs that do I/O or could otherwise be long-running are asynchronous. So that `send` call will immediately return, and the callback you passed to `onSuccess` will be scheduled by Vert.x once the response is received. Other code will be able to execute in the same thread in the 30 seconds the request is pending.

As stated in the [Vert.x docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_dont_block_me):

> With very few exceptions (i.e. some file system operations ending in 'Sync'), none of the APIs in Vert.x block the calling thread.
>
> If a result can be provided immediately, it will be returned immediately, otherwise you will usually provide a handler to receive events some time later.
>
> Because none of the Vert.x APIs block threads that means you can use Vert.x to handle a lot of concurrency using just a small number of threads.