# Synchronous API call in Vert.x and return the value with WebClient

Tags: java, vert.x

I am new to Vert.x

My goal is to consume a Rest API, let's call it CRUD-API, using the Webclient class provided by VertX. CRUD-API requires an ID and returns a json object in the body of the response.

My problem is that my Consumer verticle returns before the call made with webclient executes.

This is my code:

```
public class WebClientGetById extends AbstractVerticle {

    private String output;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        //DO NOTHING
    }

    public String getById(String myId) {
        output = null;
        vertx.executeBlocking(p -> {
            WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
            client
                    .get(8666, "localhost", "/getById")
                    .putHeader("id", myId)
                    .send()
                    .onSuccess(getSuccesssHandler());
        });
        return output;//THIS LINE IS EXECUTED BEFORE ONSUCCESS
    }

    private Handler<HttpResponse<Buffer>> getSuccesssHandler() {
        return new Handler<HttpResponse<Buffer>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpResponse<Buffer> response) {
                if (response.statusCode() == HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()) {
                    output = response.bodyAsString();
                } else {
                    output = "Got error from server " + response.statusCode();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is the code that creates the webclient and tries to consume CRUD-API:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebClientGetById  verticle = new WebClientGetById ();
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(verticle);
        String result = verticle.getById("myId");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

As you can see from the commented line, the execution reaches the last line of getById() before webclient send() returns its value. So null is always returned by getById.

A part of this similar question seems to suggest to use executeBlocking to achieve my goal.

[Is the vertx WebClient.send() method blocking or non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698129/is-the-vertx-webclient-send-method-blocking-or-non-blocking)

But i tried it and it did not work.

So, what is the Vert.x right way of achieving this goal?

(A piece of working code is preferred over a generic theoretical explanation)

**EDIT**

Based on many answers i tried to use a Future object. The only way i can make it work with this approach is by modifying the client like so (assuming the verticle returns a Future object), but i am really not sure that this working approach is graceful:

```
private String getVerticleOutput(String myId, WebClientGetById webClientGetById) {
        Future<String> future = webClientGetById.getById(myId);
        int counter = 0;
        while(!future.isComplete() || counter>5) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            counter++;
        }
        if(future.failed()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("invalid request");
        }
        return future.result();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise parameter in `executeBlocking` is used to pass the result to the caller asynchronously with one prerequisite:

- the caller can only return value asynchronously

that's why I change the return type from `string` to `Future<String>` in the following code. The philosophy here is that in the asynchronous programming model, you have to do all things asynchronously (you may argue that you can do something to wait for the result, but it's anti-pattern in most cases). The output field can be deleted to simplify the code (if you don't mind):

```java
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;

public class WebClientGetById extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() {
    //DO NOTHING
  }

  public Future<String> getById(String myId) {
    return vertx.executeBlocking(
        promise -> {
          WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
          client
              .get(8666, "localhost", "/getById")
              .putHeader("id", myId)
              .send()
              .compose(response -> {
                if (response.statusCode() == HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()) {
                  promise.complete(response.bodyAsString());
                } else {
                  promise.fail("Got error from server " + response.statusCode());
                }
                return Future.succeededFuture();
              })
              .onFailure(promise::fail);
        });
  }
}
```

To test your verticle method, you can call with:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebClientGetById  verticle = new WebClientGetById ();
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(verticle);
    verticle.getById("myId")
        .onSuccess(ret -> {
          System.out.println(ret);
        })
        .onFailure(exception -> {
          // please never forget error handling
          // do some log here
        });
  }
```

But honestly, you can do it without a verticle instance:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    client
        .get(8666, "localhost", "/getById")
        .putHeader("id", "xx")
        .send()
        .onSuccess(response -> {
          if (response.statusCode() == HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()) {
            System.out.println(response.bodyAsString());
          } else {
            System.out.println("Got error from server " + response.statusCode());
          }
        })
        .onFailure(exception -> {
          // do some log here
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i believe your response answer my question so i am going to accept it and vote it. Could you just make 2 adjustments? 1) Delete the snippet WITH output field 2) can you add a snippet of code that shows how graceful handling of a Future<String> object should be done by the client in order to get the result?

Comment: @BabaNew checked the modified version

Comment: I am sorry, i haven't properly specified what i was intending with "client"... Please see the modified version of my question

Comment: @BabaNew you do not build a `client` yet. your code just deployed the verticle, which is a server(provider) in some way. And it does not provide a way for others (real client) to make call to it. You should publish your api to event bus or as a http endpoint, thus the `real client` can make call to it and consume the result. And that's another story, you sould have a look at the official docs of vert.x web and vertx evet bus.

Comment: I edited my question to be even more clear about what my initial idea is... So, you are saying that webclient should only be used to communicate between 2 server programs? Hence vertx does not provide a client functionality like for instance httpclient of apache?

Comment: @BabaNew Get! I updated my answer so you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Wait... i don't want to print to stdout the result of the call.. i want to return it as outcome of a function.... I need to use the outcome of the function outside this class. Is this possible?

Comment: @BabaNew of course you can, as I said, `in the asynchronous programming model, you have to do all things asynchronously`. So you can return Futrure<String> easily.

Comment: Ok... so we return to the initial question... can you add code to show how to gracefully get result out of Future<String>?

Comment: hi @BabaNew the next `compose` or `onSuccess` chained API call to future is the correct way to `gracefully get result out of Future<String>`, regardless you are making the call from the same class or on other class.

Comment: Well... thanks for your responses... but you cannot return a string from onSuccess, no matter where onSuccess is chained

Comment: After poking around a bit with the vertx library i found some way to achieve what i want... i will edit my question to show you... this approach actually works, but based on what you suggested i am not sure that this is the proper way to do this in vertx

Comment: @BabaNew the code you finally used is to turn async code to sync code, which is what I mentioned - the `anti-pattern` way, as it will cause the main event loop to be blocked for an unknown length of time, which is not acceptable in vertx philosophy. You can use it to test, but we should not use it in production code in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

> the execution reaches the last line of getById function before webclient send returns its value

This sentence shows you do not understand how async programming works - before using vertx you need to learn the fundamentals of asynchronous programming.

> executeBlocking would help but it seems useless.

Execute blocking is to offload blocking calls onto a non-eventloop thread - it does not suddenly change how async code works

> return output;//this line is executed before onSuccess!!!

Yes, that is expected and how async code works

1. There is no way to 'return' a value from an onSuccess or callback - you have to compose work via futures and handlers
2. if you want to write async code that is able to execute and run sequentially you should ditch java and use kotlin with coroutines instead - doing an await call will give you the result and then you can return that from the function like normal code

You can learn more about how to use vertx and async code using my udemy course https://www.udemy.com/course/backend-development-with-vertx/learn/?referralCode=063C2D57CCB957C5088C

or reach out for 1 on 1 sessions at https://consulting.aawadia.dev